# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined / React App crashing

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue where my app crashes upon searching. I suspect this is because at some point during rendering the artist container is trying to render the code but there is no image url even so when I put a backup URL e.g. `src={props.artist.images[0].url || "backup url"}` it still fails. If y try to just load artist name I have no issues but the image is the Achilles heel here. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why it is crashing but to no avail.

Also artist container should only be rendering if we do have artist results ... so a bit confused as to why it is saying URL not defined. 99% of these results have images.

```js
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
const [artistResults, setArtistResults] = useState(null)
        
const fetchQueryArtists = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`${ApiUrl}/search?q=${query}&type=artist`, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + props.token
            }
        })
    
        if (response.ok) {
            let json = await response.json()
            console.log(json.artists.items)
            setArtistResults(json.artists.items)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (query.length > 1) {
        fetchQueryArtists()
        fetchQueryTracks()
        fetchQueryAlbums()
    }
}, [query])
```

Inside my return is this:

```js
{query.length > 0 && artistResults &&
                        <h3 className="py-3 px-2">Artists</h3>}
    
{artistResults && artistResults.length > 0 ? artistResults.slice(0, 6).map(artist => {
    return <ArtistContainer key={artist.id} artist={artist} />
}) : <h1>Test flag</h1>}
```

This is my artist container:

```js
return (
    <div onClick={directToPlaylist} className="category-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center  mb-4 col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
        <img  className="img-fluid" height={150} src={props.artist.images[0].url} alt="playlist-cover" />
        <div>
            <span>{props.artist.name}</span>
            <p className="text-muted">Artist</p>
        </div>             
    </div>
);
```

This is the JSON (just in case you think I am accessing the images incorrectly):

```
Array(20)
0:
external_urls: {spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"}
followers: {href: null, total: 55327781}
genres: (6) ["canadian hip hop", "canadian pop", "hip hop", "pop rap", "rap", "toronto rap"]
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
id: "3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
images: Array(3)
0: {height: 640, url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/60cfab40c6bb160a1906be45276829d430058005", width: 640}
1: {height: 320, url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/5ea794cf832550943d5f8122afcf5f23ee9d85b7", width: 320}
2: {height: 160, url: "https://i.scdn.co/image/8eaace74aaca82eaccde400bbcab2653b9cf86e1", width: 160}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
name: "Drake"
popularity: 98
type: "artist"
uri: "spotify:artist:3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
src={props.artist.images[0]?.url || "backup url"}
```

I've use something called as optional chaining here. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

**Detailed Explanation**:

1. Before the api call, the react renders the component, that time:
   `props.artist.images = []`.
2. So before we fetch the data, it would be an empty array, accessing first element of that gives undefined.
3. Therefore, you try to access `undefined.url`, this gives an error.

**Now more about optional chaining**:

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Traditionally if we have to safely access nested elements, we do:

```
const obj = {
  name: {
    first: "foo",
    last: "bar"
  }
};
// Getting first element
const firstName = obj && obj.name && obj.name.first ? obj.name.first : "fallback";

// optional chaining
const firstElement = obj?.name?.first || "fallback"
```

Summarising example:

```js
// This raises TypeError
console.log(undefined.someKey)
```

```js
// Optinal chaining gives safety net and does not give TypeError
console.log(undefined?.somKey);
```

About Browser Support and Usage:
This may not work with older browser due to compatibility issue. Check [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining)

Also note, if you're using Typescript > `3.7` then optional chaining can work for older browsers as well (since Babel accordingly transpiles to target the configured browsers).

Comment: this works friend. thanks a bunch. I am a bit confused as to why my check wasn't working though. Reading the docs on null collescing but don't understand it

Comment: Give me a min, I'll explain bit more in my example @mycodegoesKABOOM

Comment: ok no problem. thanks a lot for taking time to explain.

Comment: I've done edit, the feature is `optional chaining` and not `null coalescing`.

Comment: "Before the api call, the react renders the component, that time: props.artist.images = []." The artist container should not render until we have the data back from the api though due to this check "
                {artistResults && artistResults.length > 0 ? artistResults.slice(0, 6).map(artist => {
                    return <ArtistContainer key={artist.id} artist={artist} />
                }) : <h1>Test flag</h1>}".  At that point we would have the images so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

props.artist[0].images[0]?.url || "backup url"

instead of

props.artist.images[0].url

Comment: thanks Harsh, this syntax works props.artist.images[0]?.url || "backup url"